# Google map is not loading on chrome and firefox but working perfectly on safari LARAVEL

Tags: jquery, html, css, laravel-4

[Please click here:Video of the browser](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feI10Q5ooVI)Google map is not loading on chrome and firefox but working perfectly on safari

If i am reducing the screen of browser it is working for full screen its not.
Getting following error

div.querySelectorAll("*,:x"); exception jquery-1.10.2.js

```
<div class="box box-success">
</br>
<div class="col-md-8">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="my-address" placeholder="Please enter your address">
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" id="flow2">
<button id="getCords" class="btn btn-success" onClick="codeAddress();">Find Location</button>
</div>
</br>
<div id="map" style="height:600px;width:100%;margin-top:30px;"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="latitude" id="latitude">
<input type="hidden" name="longitude" id="longitude">


</div>



<!-- map page js starts -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var popup_pin = "";
var markersArray = [];
var newmarkersArray = [];
var customIcons = {
restaura3t: {
icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
      shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
        },
bar: {
icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
      shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
     },
client: {
icon: '<?php echo asset_url(); ?>/image/client-70.png',
      shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
    },
client_no_pay: {
icon: '<?php echo asset_url(); ?>/image/client-red.png',
      shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
           },
client_pay_done: {
icon: '<?php echo asset_url(); ?>/image/client_pay_done.png',
      shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
         },
driver: {
icon: '<?php echo asset_url(); ?>/image/driver-70.png',
      shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
    }
};


function load(lat,lng) {
    var latitude='';
    var longitude='';
    if(lat!=''){latitude=lat;longitude=lng;}else{latitude=<?= $center_latitude ?>;longitude=<?= $center_longitude ?>;}

    var address = (document.getElementById('my-address'));
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address);
    autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
            }


            var address = '';
            if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
            (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
            (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
            (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
            }
            });

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            {     center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
zoom: 10,     mapTypeId: 'roadmap' }); 

    var infoWindow = new
        google.maps.InfoWindow; 
    (function() {     var f = function() {
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
     downloadUrl("{{ URL::Route('AdminProviderXml') }}",
         function(data) {             
         var xml = data.responseXML;
         var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
         popup_pin = "";             
         for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
         var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name"); 
         var client_name = markers[i].getAttribute("client_name"); 
         var contact = markers[i].getAttribute("contact");
         var amount = markers[i].getAttribute("amount"); 
         var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type"); 
         var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");
         var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
             parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
             parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))); 
         var html = ""; 
         if(type == 'client_pay_done') {     
         html = "<b>" + client_name + "</b></p><p><span class ='icon-phone' style=''></span><span style='margin-left:5px;'><br>" + contact + "</span></p><b>"; 
         } else if (type == 'client') {
         html = "<b>" + client_name + "</b></p><p><span class ='icon-phone' style=''></span><span style='margin-left:5px;'><br>" + contact + "</span></p><b>"; 
         } else {     
             html = "<b>" + client_name + "</b></p><p><span class ='icon-phone' style=''></span><span style='margin-left:5px;'><br>" + contact + "</span></p><b>"; 
         } 

         var icon = customIcons[type] || {}; marker =
             new google.maps.Marker({     map: map,     position: point,
                     icon: icon.icon,     shadow: icon.shadow });
         newmarkersArray.push(marker); bindInfoWindow(marker, map,
                 infoWindow, html, type, name, popup_pin);             }
         clearOverlays(markersArray);             markersArray =
             newmarkersArray;             newmarkersArray = [];         });
    };     window.setInterval(f, 15000);     f();

    var legendDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
    var legend = new Legend(legendDiv, map);
    legendDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP].push(legendDiv);

    })();
}


function clearOverlays(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i].setMap(null);
    }
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html, type, name, popup_pin) {
    if (name == popup_pin) {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        popup_pin = "";
    }
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            if (type == 'client') {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            } else if (type == 'client_pay_done') {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }   
            });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}


function initialize() {

}

function codeAddress() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("my-address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            // initialize_map(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());
            load(latitude,longitude);
            //         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            // var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            //     center: latlng,
            //     zoom: 11,
            //     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            // });
            // var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            //     position: latlng,
            //     map: map,
            //     title: 'Set lat/lon values for this property',
            //     draggable: true
            // });
            } 

            else {
                //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
    });
}


function doNothing() {
}



function Legend(controlDiv, map) {
    // Set CSS styles for the DIV containing the control
    // Setting padding to 5 px will offset the control
    // from the edge of the map
    controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

    // Set CSS for the control border
    var controlUI = document.createElement('DIV');
    controlUI.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
    controlUI.style.borderWidth = '1px';
    controlUI.title = 'Legend';
    controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);

    // Set CSS for the control text
    var controlText = document.createElement('DIV');
    controlText.style.fontFamily = 'Arial,sans-serif';
    controlText.style.fontSize = '12px';
    controlText.style.paddingLeft = '4px';
    controlText.style.paddingRight = '4px';

    // Add the text
    controlText.innerHTML = '<b>Legends</b><br />' +
        '<img src="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>/image/client-70.png" style="height:25px;"/> Available<br />' +
        '<img src="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>/image/client_pay_done.png" style="height:25px;"/> On a Walk<br />' +
        '<img src="<?php echo asset_url(); ?>/image/client-red.png" style="height:25px;"/> Inactive<br />' +
        '<small>*Data is fictional</small>';
    controlUI.appendChild(controlText);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', load('',''));

</script>


@stop
```

Comment: Please, provide more information.

Comment: Show your google maps js code. Are there errors in the developer console?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what changes you made to the database and PHP. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: I have added screen shot of warning i am getting